# Python - Format variable inside string

Tags: python

I have a problem.
I want to assign a path to a variable, so I did this:

```
customers = ["john", "steve", "robbert", "benjamin"]
for customer in customers:
    dataset = "/var/www/test.nl/customer_data/" + str({customer}) + ".csv"
```

So I was hoping that the output of that variable would be:

```
/var/www/test.nl/customer_data/john.csv
```

But that's not the case, because the output I get is:

```
/var/www/test.nl/customer_data/set(['john']).csv
```

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Here you first make a singleton *`set`* that contains that string. As a result it is formatted the wrong way. With:

```
str({customer})
```

you thus first construct a set, for example:

```
>>> {"john"}
{'john'}
>>> type({"john"})
<class 'set'>
```

and if you then take the `str(..)` of that set, we get:

```
>>> str({"john"})
"{'john'}"
```

So then this is the value we will "fill in", whereas we only want the content of the string `customer` itself.

You can format these with:

```
customers = ["john", "steve", "robbert", "benjamin"]
for customer in customers:
    dataset = "/var/www/test.nl/customer_data/{}.csv".format(customer)
```

So here `{}` will be replaced with the string representation of `customer`, but since `customer` is already a string, it will thus simply fill in the string.

Answer (score 2):

You have curly braces around the `customer` variable. Replace

```
dataset = "/var/www/test.nl/customer_data/" + str({customer}) + ".csv"
```

with

```
dataset = "/var/www/test.nl/customer_data/" + str(customer) + ".csv"
```

Better yet, if on python 3.6 or higher, use f strings:

```
dataset = f"/var/www/test.nl/customer_data/{customer}.csv"
```

That might be where you've seen curly braces used for string formatting. The way you're using them, you are defining a `set` object inline.